# When is prime $\mathfrak p$ the intersection of all proper primes containing it?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I am looking for a name/reference to this property(I call it **reachable** for now)

> A prime ideal $\mathfrak p\subset A$ is called **reachable** if it is the intersection of all proper prime ideals containing it, i.e., $$\mathfrak p=\bigcap_{\mathfrak q\supset \mathfrak p, \mathfrak q\neq \mathfrak p}\mathfrak q$$

Here is a highly non-trivial result of interest:

> Let $f: A\to B$ be a finite type ring map, and $\mathfrak p\subset B$ is a prime ideal. If $f^{-1}(\mathfrak p)$ is **reachable**, then $\mathfrak p$ is also **reachable**.

For a ring map, preserving **reachable** primes is weaker than going-up, but going up definitely fails for a finite type ring map. Usually we require it to be intergal.

Is there a name/some reference to this property of interest?

Comment: You should re-define reachable to automatically include maximal ideals. With this modification, every prime is reachable iff the ring is Jacobson. For a Noetherian ring, any prime of dimension $\ge 2$ is always reachable. In particular, TFAE for a Noetherian ring $R$: (i) $R$ is Jacobson, (ii) every prime of dim $1$ is reachable, (iii) every prime of dim $1$ is contained in infinitely many maximal ideals

Comment: Another general fact: a prime $\mathfrak{p}$ is not reachable iff there exists $f \in R$ such that the localization $(R/\mathfrak{p})_f$ is a field. Equivalently, $\{ \mathfrak{p} \}$ is open in $V(\mathfrak{p})$

Answer (score 1):

To put it in terms of something that exists in the literature, $\mathfrak {p}$ is reachable iff it is not a **Goldman ideal**. See [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/187892/19965) to see why $R/\mathfrak{p}$ is not Goldman, and the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldman_domain).